# What is the purpose of flash-integration.swc?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

With Flex 4 a new library called flash-integration.swc was introduced to the SDK. Does anybody know what the purpose of this library is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It contains `mx.flash.UIMovieClip`, `mx.flash.ContainerMovieClip` and `mx.flash.FlexContentHolder` which are the part of Adobe Flash Component Kit for Flex and produces integration of Flash content within Flex applications. You can read more [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/flash/UIMovieClip.html).

Comment: Thanx for the link and the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It was made into it's own standalone SWC, branched off from utilities.swc.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/534762?tstart=-1

The SWC appears to simply contain a few libraries and one component. You can find this nfo in a truncated version of the SWC's catalog below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<swc xmlns="http://www.adobe.com/flash/swccatalog/9">
  <versions>
    <swc version="1.2" />
    <flex version="4.5.0" build="19786" minimumSupportedVersion="3.0.0" />
  </versions>
  <features>
    <feature-script-deps />
    <feature-components />
    <feature-files />
  </features>
  <components>
    <component className="mx.flash:FlexContentHolder" name="FlexComponentBase" uri="http://www.adobe.com/someNonSensicalURI"  />
  </components>
  <libraries>
    <library path="library.swf">
      <script name="mx/flash/UIMovieClip" mod="1294360346590" signatureChecksum="2489211033" >
      </script>
      <script name="mx/flash/ContainerMovieClip" mod="1288903295049" signatureChecksum="747581936" >
      </script>
      <script name="mx/flash/FlexContentHolder" mod="1275497612711" signatureChecksum="3383159784" >
      </script>
      <script name="_5388b587d6475d1d70347b16048793ca2fd9ec82f1792157b30dade9a418de69_flash_display_Sprite" mod="1295301928226" signatureChecksum="2221373773" >
      </script>
    </library>
  </libraries>
  <files>
  </files>
</swc>
```